# Flutter Push notification not displaying on IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, apple-push-notifications

I am having an issue with Flutter and IOS in regards to Push notifications.

My setup and things that work:

1) I installed the `firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6` package with no errors / followed all their instructions for IOS

2) I have asked user permission on IOS and accepted to receive push notifications

3) I am able to get an FCM token on IOS & Android devices

4) I have created a Key in the Apple developer section and added the key to FCM

5) I have closed the app / sent it to the background when testing - still no luck

6) I have added the google-service-info file to Runner using Xcode

7) I have added push notifications and background notifications in XCode Capabilities

8) I am testing on an iPhone 7 physical device, and a physical iPad

I have used curl to send a notification to an IOS device

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<myAuthKEY>" \
    --Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
    -d "{\"to\":\"<myDeviceKey>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Hello\"},\"priority\":10}"
```

I get a success response from firebase

```
{"multicast_id":<SomeIdHere>,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"<SomeIdHere>"}]}
```

Here is how I retrieve the token:

```
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      _authModel.setNotificationToken(token);
    });
```

When I run the app on IOS, I do not get any Firebase errors.

I've been messing around with this for 2 days now, so it's getting a bit annoying, all the above seems to work on Android.

Any suggestions, please.

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A583, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

My AppDelegate.m file

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FIRApp configure];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think it is related to FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled. https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723 This link will be helpful.

Comment: The link seems off, the archive one is still active: https://web.archive.org/web/20191118225834/https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723 but without images :(

Comment: This one seems good as well: https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e

Comment: Are you able to send them using the firebase messaging console?

Comment: @user3057745 Do you resolve this issue?

Comment: Anyone resolved it. Facing the issue :(

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, you may need to provide a lot more details, but please file this issue to https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues. Otherwise, a quick search of [iOS push notification](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=iOS%20push%20notification%20is%3Aopen) issues shows variety of reports. Here are some similar ones, maybe one is related yours?

- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1799

  - Only shows in foreground, RE: `5) I have closed the app / sent it to the background when testing - still no luck`
- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1590

  - related to the background issue
- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1797

  - did you try from the console?, RE: Stefano Saitta's comment
- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1677

  - works on Android, but not iOS
- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1581

  - other plugins can break it?

Or if you already filed one, share the link! Others may add feedback to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have to complete all the steps from https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging carefully. I was also stuck in it. But later I realized am missing something. Then I recheck all the steps. I missed registering with APN(Apple Push Notification).So please recheck once again.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you missed and how its fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I followed the official guide of flutter fire but it is unfortunate that it has not provided certain necessary steps of iOS configuration which I found somewhere else.

I added below line to Info.plist file

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key><false/>
```

and added firebase configuration in appdelegate.swift file and notification started working.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
     Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was trying to find where is the problem in my AppDelegate and just found your code is corrected my code exactly!

Answer (score -1):

If you are testing on ios 10 plush device then try by adding below lines to your AppDelegate.swift file below FirebaseApp.configure()

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

Comment: This is actually an error of firebase_messaging documentation, as mentioned here : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1677#issuecomment-597882813 and other github issues