# Flutter push notifications using FCM not working on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been attempting for weeks to get push notifications to work properly on iOS to no avail. I have combed through the documentation to verify my config. The push notifications are working properly for Android however.

I have also tested sending messages directly from the firebase messaging console to IOS and am still unsuccessful.  I've also tried many of the suggestions in previous stack overflow posts with no success.

[Flutter IOS FCM push notification not coming into notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503422/flutter-ios-fcm-push-notification-not-coming-into-notification-bar)

[Flutter Push notification not displaying on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300407/flutter-push-notification-not-displaying-on-ios)

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1677

[iOS FirebaseCloudMessaging Notifications not working in Debug / Test Flight nor Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507900/ios-firebasecloudmessaging-notifications-not-working-in-debug-test-flight-nor)

I am using a physical iPhone 12 on iOS 14.6. The version of Xcode I'm on is 12.5.
Xcode is configured as follows.

Signing and Capabilities
[image: Signing and Capabilities]

Signing
[image: Signing]

Code for the app delegate file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

   Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
   super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
 }
}
```

Code for how push notifications are requested

```
Future<void> notficationsPermission () async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: true,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: true,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);


print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');


String uid = Pref.getString(Keys.USER_ID);
var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
if(settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized){
  notficationStatus = true; 
 await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
   
  alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);
}

else{
  notficationStatus = false;  
}
}
}
```

Snippet of how notifications are configured

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
                            topicName, {
                              android: {
                                priority: "high",
                              },
                              // Add APNS (Apple) config
                              apns: {
                                payload: {
                                  aps: {
                                    contentAvailable: true,
                                  },
                                },
                                headers: {
                                  "apns-push-type": "background",
                                  "apns-priority": "5", // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
                                  "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
                                },
                              },
                              notification: {
                                title: snapshot2.val().group_name +
                                  ": new chat message",
                                body: name +":"+snapshot.val().message,
                                clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                              },
                            });
```

I also having the following in my Info.plist.

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <string>0</string>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding   "content_available": true in the notification JSON?

Comment: @KathanPatel Yes I did and that didn't work either!

Comment: Are you trying to send notification to specific topic ? If yes then have you checked that your iOS device have faced any error while subscribing that topic.

Comment: Yes I have tried subscribing to a particular topic and it is successful pushed on Android.

Comment: @IsisCuriel I'm having same issue, could you fix it?

Comment: @DNS I did! I'll post the answer shortly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out but forgot to post the answer!
in my index.js

```
exports.chatNotfi = functions.database.ref("messages/{gId}/{chat}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{
  const groupId = context.params.gId;
  console.log("Group id:" + groupId);
  const topicName = groupId + "chat";
  console.log("topic name"+topicName);
  const userId = snapshot.val().userId;
  return admin.database().ref("groups/"+groupId+ "/").once("value").
      then((snapshot2)=>{
       
                    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
                        topicName, {
                          notification: {
                            title:
                              ": New chat message",
                            body: name +":"+snapshot.val().message,
                            clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                          },
                        });
});
```

In my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
 [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
  launchOptions)
  }
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

   Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
   super.application(application, 
   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
 }
}
```

In my Info.plist

```
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Also make sure that the app registered in the firebase console matches the bundle identifier used in Xcode.

Comment: i am also having issues with this ios push notification

Comment: Yes I am successfully sending to IOS 14

Comment: now if i send from firebase console is going through but on foreground the local push notification is not showing the message.

Comment: I think there is a setting you have to configure to be able to see your Ios notifications in foreground. I believe you need alert :true in the following config.

Comment: await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
   
  alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);

Comment: thanks for this even reading about the properties when i hover my mouse tells it all. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple cases why you're not getting heads-up notifications

After the recent changes to the SDK, you don't have to show the push notifications manually using packages like fontawesomenotifications, etc the SDK will itself handle the heads-up notifications in the background and foreground if it identifies it as a background/Notification type, But if you're using earlier SDK you manually have to write fontawesomenotifications.show() in foreground message listener if you wrote this fontawesomenotifications.show() in the latest SDK you ,might be getting notifications twice

I'm using a custom Django backend to trigger push notifications to my Flutter application and here is the code

[image: Django code showing how to send a push notification with Firebase admin]

Keep in mind to add content_available=True and sound='default' for ios so that the SDK will consider it as a Notification type and pop a heads-up notification with sound

This worked for me !!